# Slow alter queries MySql openjpa

Tags: mysql, sql, openjpa, flyway

Few days ago all alter table statements executed by openjpa for MySql database slowed down terribly - one statement executes in 5 seconds. My tables are all empty - all the alter statements are only a part of creating test data for my system, so it is not a problem of volume of the data. Executing one statement in such a time is not an option - there is like thousand of alter table statements.

I tried to execute all the sql I needed from phpMyAdmin - worked fine and nice, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

My openjpa version is 2.2.2, MySql 5.6.14

I'm wondering if migrating the database with flyway has any to do with this terrible performance.

Does anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway executes the statements you pass it. Nothing more. So I strongly doubt this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was a problem with mySql version - with downgrade to 5.5.34 everything works like it should.